# Getting Localtime using timezone.now()

Tags: django, timezone, pytz

I'm performing a query where I want to get a list of items added today.

```py
listOfMatches = Matches.objects.filter(
    match_starting_time__date=timezone.localdate(timezone.now())
)
```

Also tried this

```py
listOfMatches=Matches.objects.filter(match_starting_time__date=timezone.now())
```

All I'm getting is Utc time

```py
print(timezone.now())
```

I need Local time. I have set Time_zone to

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Pacific/Fiji'
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I mean, does it hurt to use `UTC+12`? Should be the equivalent of Fiji/Pacific time

Comment: Friend, dont need approx time. It is 27th in fiji and 26th in utc. Timezone.now() is showing 26th(UTC).